# How to manually deploy 3rd party utility jar for Apache Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Apache Spark cluster (multi-nodes) and I would like to manually deploy some utility jars to each Spark node. Where should I put these jars to?
For example: spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.0.jar

I know we can use maven to build a fat jar which including these jars, however I would like to deploy these utilities manually. In this way, programmers would not have to deploy these utilities jars.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a problem with simply copying them onto the classpath?

Comment: I am pretty new for Apache Spark. The "classpath" you mentioned is the same as  Spark environment: "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath" ?

Comment: Hmm, that might work. I usually simply copy stuff onto a directory already on the classpath ("/usr/lib/hadoop/" on AWS EMR-4.2).

Comment: Oh!! Ok, I got it. I just need to check my system environment [$CLASSPATH] and places these 3rd party jars there.

Comment: Yep, you've got it :-)

Comment: why dont you just simply copy them to shared hdfs directory? it is manageable, please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

1, Copy your 3rd party jars to reserved HDFS directory;
for example `hdfs://xxx-ns/user/xxx/3rd-jars/`

2, In spark-submit, specify these jars using hdfs path;
`hdfs:` - executors will pull down files and JARs from hdfs directory

```
--jars hdfs://xxx-ns/user/xxx/3rd-jars/xxx.jar
```

3, spark-submit will not repleatly upload these jars

```
Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying hdfs://xxx-ns/user/xxx/3rd-jars/xxx.jar
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, could you explain more detail or provide a sample how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

spark-submit and spark-shell have a `--jars` option. This will distribute the jars to all the executors. The `spark-submit --help` for --jars is as follows

```
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
```

This is taken from the [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell)..

```
Or, to also add code.jar to its classpath, use:
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --jars code.jar
```